# Best practise to compute total amount from individual entries

Tags: database-design, update, sum

I want to keep track of the individual and total amount of drinks someone ordered.

Table 1 Customer information:

```
customer_id name    age
1           Steve   44
4           John    24
```

Table 2 Drink orders:

```
cusomter_id (foreignkey)    drink_name  date
1                           Cola        17/09/2021 - 4PM
4                           Fanta       17/09/2021 - 3PM
1                           Coffee      16/09/2021 - 1PM
1                           Apple Juice 14/09/2021 - 4PM
```

For all customers I want to keep track of the total amount of drinks they ordered.

So in this example that would be 3 drinks for customer 1 and 1 drink for customer 4.

How would I go about this?

Should I add another column inside table 1 called "tot_amount_drinks" that is increased everytime a new entry in table 2 is made? If so is it possible to code this increase as a kind of database constraint (I tried to look it up, but do not know the jargon). Or is it better to practise to sum all drinks per customer from table 2everytime the total amount of drinks is needed, which seems time consuming as tabel 2 can become vary large.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is:

```
 Should I add another column inside table 1 called 
 "tot_amount_drinks" that is increased everytime a 
 new entry in table 2 is made?
```

Well, for starters, you should be doing something like this (a fiddle for all the code below is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2892fe116017c35a5e81fb127cffd41d) - you haven't specified a server so I chose PostgreSQL - the code should work with pretty much any RDBMS with a little tweaking):

```
CREATE TABLE customer 
(
  customer_id INTEGER  NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  name        TEXT     NOT NULL,
  
  yob         SMALLINT NOT NULL,  -- year of birth
                                  -- choose appropriate data type 
                                  -- for your server...
  
  CONSTRAINT customer_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);
```

and

```
INSERT INTO customer (name, yob) VALUES
('Steve', 1980),
('John' , 1990);
```

Purchases:

```
CREATE TABLE purchase
(
  cust_id    INTEGER        NOT NULL,
  drink_name TEXT           NOT NULL,
  bill       NUMERIC        NOT NULL,
  currency   TEXT           NOT NULL,
  p_ts       TIMESTAMPTZ(0) NOT NULL, -- (0) if purchases to the second/millisecond aren't necessary

  CONSTRAINT pur_cust_fk FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES customer (customer_id)
);
```

Populate:

```
INSERT INTO purchase VALUES
(1, 'Cola',        3.5, 'Euro', '2021-09-17 16:00'), 
(2, 'Fanta',       3.5, 'Euro', '2021-09-17 15:00'),
(1, 'Coffee',      3.0, 'Euro', '2021-09-16 13:00'),
(1, 'Apple Juice', 1.8, 'Euro', '2021-09-14 16:00');
```

And then, your SQL will look something like this:

```
SELECT
  c.customer_id, name, 
  DATE_PART('YEAR', NOW()) - yob AS age, SUM(p.bill), p.currency
FROM
  customer c
JOIN purchase p
  ON c.customer_id = p.cust_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id, p.currency;
```

Result:

```
customer_id     name    age     sum     currency
          1     Steve   41      8.3     Euro
          2     John    31      3.5     Euro
```

A few suggestions:

- don't use `age` as a field! Age is mutable and will change from year to year, so you'll have to update your table on an annual basis, with all the attendant risks of missing deadlines, data-entry errors and whatnot. Use `yob` (year of birth) which will **never** change and perform calculations on that.
- **always** use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for timestamps (i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.sss...`) - it's, err..., the standard, and using it everywhere throughout your code will make life simpler and eliminate possibilities for error!
- it's also best to get into the habit of using timestamps with time zones - these never change despite daylight savings/timezone changes and will make your data portable!
- it might be best (depending on your use case) to have different currencies?

So, you can then do stuff like this.

Add more records for drinks purchased 10 years ago:

```
INSERT INTO purchase VALUES -- cheaper prices 10 years ago!

(1, 'Cola',        2.5, 'Euro', '2010-09-17 16:00'), 
(2, 'Fanta',       2.5, 'Euro', '2010-09-17 15:00'),
(1, 'Coffee',      2.0, 'Euro', '2010-09-16 13:00'),
(1, 'Apple Juice', 0.8, 'Euro', '2010-09-14 16:00');
```

And then you can query your data as follows:

```
SELECT
  c.customer_id, c.name, 
  DATE_PART('YEAR', p.p_ts) - c.yob AS purchase_age, 
  SUM(p.bill), p.currency,
  COUNT(p.p_ts) AS drinks_count
FROM
  customer c
JOIN purchase p
  ON c.customer_id = p.cust_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id, DATE_PART('YEAR', p.p_ts), p.currency
ORDER BY c.customer_id, purchase_age;
```

Result:

```
customer_id     name    purchase_age    sum     currency    drinks_count
          1     Steve             30    5.3         Euro             3
          1     Steve             41    8.3         Euro             3
          2     John              20    2.5         Euro             1
          2     John              31    3.5         Euro             1
```

Which gives you a breakdown of the `SUM()` of the purchases by purchase age and the number of drinks purchased (`COUNT()`). I didn't put in anything to do with [currency conversion](https://www.back4app.com/database/back4app/currency-dataset) and or estimated current value of all purchases and all of that other fun stuff - I leave that to the reader!

You could also have a `product` table so that users can't enter free text - it's **always** advisable to restrict what users can enter into your database. If you allow users to enter rubbish, they'll find a way (many ways...) of entering rubbish, but I think we're going a bit beyond scope now! :-) Thanks to @HannahVernon for pointing that out.

So, finally, to answer to the question.

**Normally**, the answer would be no, you shouldn't add running totals in parent tables because this breaches the principle that information should be stored in [one place and one place only](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/wm-computerapplicationsmgrs-2/chapter/database-principles/):

> A database is a shared collection of related data used to support the
> activities of a particular organization. A database can be viewed as a
> repository of data that is defined once and then accessed by various
> users.

This is because having the same data in the same place **can** lead to [update anomalies](https://databasemanagement.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Data_Anomalies):

> An update anomaly is a data inconsistency that results from data
> redundancy and a partial update. For example, each employee in a
> company has a department associated with them as well as the student
> group they participate in.

[image]

> If A. Bruchs’ department is an error it must be updated at least 2
> times or there will be inconsistent data in the database. If the user
> performing the update does not realize the data is stored redundantly
> the update will not be done properly.

**But**, for example if you have a huge dataset and you find that performance is suffering badly as a result of having to perform `SUM()`s , `COUNT()`s and `AVG()`s (or whatever), then you could implement a running total by means of, say, a trigger which should ensure data consistency.

So, **final answer** (no phone-a-friend, no ask-the-audience, no more lifelines...) is that, as with so much in IT, it **depends** on your requirements, your budget and your stakeholders' needs...

Re. the terminology part of the question, what you refer to as  "tot_amount_drinks" would be called a "running total" and the (canonical) mechanism for doing this is by using [triggers](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-triggers/)! So on an `INSERT` into the `purchase` table, you would have a trigger on that table to update the `running_total` field in your `customer` table.

However, this is problematic, because you then won't know the date of the purchase or the currency! You might have to apply a currency conversion on the incoming amount? You also have to consider `DELETE`s and `UPDATE`s (even though these will probably be rare...). So, as (at the great risk of sounding boring) is that "ye gets nuttin' for nuttin'!". Everything has it's *pros* and *cons*!

A final note on "SQL style"... I use singular names for tables - this is because, to my mind, a table is a set and therefore should be singular. This also has the advantage that I never have to think about it. Also, my table and field names are in lower_case with_an_underscore_as_a_separator.

There are many style guides out there ([this](https://www.sqlstyle.guide/) is a good one) - just pick a style and stick to it. Your fellow developers will thank you - and indeed, you'll thank yourself in 6 months (a year... whatever) down the line when it comes to modifying/updating your code.

Comment: I would add a table to store the product names, with a foreign key in the purchases table, but perhaps that would be getting ahead of ourselves.

Comment: @HannahVernon - the principle that users should **never** be allowed to enter free text - yep - I'll add that bit in just for completeness!